# ConfigurationSection with nullable element

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm customizing my own configuration section. I'm wondering if it is possible to return null for an element, that is not present in the config file. For instance, consider:

```
<myConfig><myElement/></myConfig>
```

This builds on top of:

```
public class MyConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
   [ConfigurationProperty ("myElement")]
   public MyElement MyElement { get { return (MyElement) this["myElement"]; } }
}
```

This will return an instance of `MyElement` even if the `<myElement/>` is not there.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I realized there is a `MyElement.ElementInformation.IsPresent` property.